# NHibernate deleting child collection object StaleObjectStateException

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am running into a problem with NHibernate and I can't quite figure out the best solution.
I have a Customer class with a child collection, and I am trying to delete an item from the collection by removing it from the list.

Class and mappings are below:

```
public class Customer : Entity<Customer>
{
    public virtual IList<WishlistProduct> Wishlist { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        Wishlist = new List<WishlistProduct>();
    }

    public virtual bool RemoveFromWishlist(int id)
    {
        bool removed = false;

        for (int x = Wishlist.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            if (Wishlist[x].Product.Id == id)
            {
                Wishlist[x].Customer = null;
                Wishlist.RemoveAt(x);
                removed = true;
            }
        }

        return removed;
    }
}
```

Mappings:

```
internal class CustomerMapping : EntityMapping<Customer>
{
    internal CustomerMapping()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Wishlist)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

internal class WishlistProductMapping : EntityMapping<WishlistProduct>
{
    internal WishlistProductMapping()
    {
        References(x => x.Customer);
    }
}
```

To delete the child I am doing something like this:

```
customer.RemoveFromWishlist(1);
```

I am using the following session management technique:

```
builder.Register(x => MyApplication.SessionFactory.OpenSession()).As<ISession>()
            .InstancePerHttpRequest()
            .OnRelease(x =>
            {
                x.Flush();
                x.Close();
            });
```

I can see from the SQL logs that this is indeed generating the correct DELETE statement to remove the record, however in the OnRelease callback I am getting a StaleObjectStateException: "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)". In the exception detail I can see it is borking on the child object that is being deleted.

Why is this occurring? I don't see how the child object is being modified anywhere prior to Flush being called. I am not doing anything to the parent object or child object other than removing the child from the list.

I know I could just delete the child object individually but the business logic seems much more natural to be able to remove the child from the parent's list and have the delete taken care of.

Any help or insight is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue, but after changing Cascade in .hbm file problem is solved. Can you please provide .hbm structure of master & child Table. Thanks,
Bhushan Babras

Comment: I'm not using XML mapping, I'm using Fluent mapping. What change to the Cascade did you make?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @jamie-ide answer.

You are using wrong [cascade type](http://ayende.com/blog/1890/nhibernate-cascades-the-different-between-all-all-delete-orphans-and-save-update) in that situation. You need to use AllDeleteOrphan():

```
internal class CustomerMapping : EntityMapping<Customer>
{
    internal CustomerMapping()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Wishlist)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed the cascade to AllDeleteOrphan, same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain both sides of the relationship by removing the item from the collection and null'ing the reference to its parent.

```
public virtual bool RemoveFromWishlist(int id)
{
    bool removed = false;

    for (int x = Wishlist.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        if (Wishlist[x].Product.Id == id)
        {
            Wishlist[x].Customer = null;
            Wishlist.RemoveAt(x);
            removed = true;
        }
    }

    return removed;
}
```

Comment: Updated as per your suggestion, nulled the parent reference, made no difference I'm sorry. Same exception.

Comment: I may not understand your domain model, you have a Product class in the mix as well. In my experience the root cause of the error you are getting is due to an item that is removed from a collection that still has a non-null foreign key set.

Comment: So then is there no way to delete the child object by just removing it from the parent collection? I am nulling the FK parent reference ... do I need to use WishlistRepository to delete the object individually?